# How to display json data in two columns in a table using angular

Tags: angularjs, json, html

I have data in my json it will be dynamic and I want to display the data in a table with two columns.  I am trying but only the first two records are repeating.   I don't see all the records in the table.. Any help?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Hnb7hkjA16XDbzRT8VAt?p=preview

```
This is my json :  var data = '{  
   "output":{  
      "service-status":[  
         {  
            "service":"db",
            "service-name":"Mongo DB"
         },
         {  
            "service":"license",
            "service-name":"Smart License"
         },
         {  
            "service":"BRM",
            "service-name":"Billing"
         },
         {  
            "service":"subscription",
            "service-name":"subscription"
         }
      ]
   }
}';
```

my html code:

```
<table  border="1px" width="100%" ng-repeat="data in serviceData" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
     <tr>
         <td>{{serviceData[index]["service-name"]}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>

i want to display something like this

Mongo Db       Smart License
Billing        subscription
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform your data in the controller:

```
var serviceDataView = function() {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.serviceData.length; i+=2){
      res.push({
        col1: $scope.serviceData[i]['service-name'], 
        col2: $scope.serviceData[i+1] ? $scope.serviceData[i+1]['service-name'] : null
      });
    }
    return res;
};

$scope.structuredData = serviceDataView();
```

So that it can be easily used in the view:

```
<table border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in structuredData">
        <td>{{data.col1}}</td>
        <td>{{data.col2}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sy0boEFIFLfdoHPKy1Co?p=preview).

Comment: That is simple each record will display in separate row.  My requirement to display the data in two columns.

Comment: I have updated the plunker here with my requirement.  http://plnkr.co/edit/kvWSDhCnWiVhT3PVLXo1?p=preview         check the comments section of html page

Comment: @Kiran, then you should prepare your data in the controller first and then use the simplified data structure in the view. Here the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sy0boEFIFLfdoHPKy1Co?p=preview)

Comment: I just saw your plunker code and yes thats what i am expecting... but I do see lots of console errors related to iteration.  do you know why is that?  I did not really get into those.  And thanks for your code.

Comment: never mind.. i have fixed that console errors..   http://plnkr.co/edit/oilP7spiYW2BRB3nAXUx?p=preview

Comment: @Kiran, my fault. I corrected the answer for the record.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator that uses ng-repeat is $index.

Others Iterator: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Replace your table for:

```
<table  border="1px" width="100%" ng-repeat="data in serviceData">
    <tr>
        <td>{{serviceData[$index]["service"]}}</td>
        <td>{{serviceData[$index]["service-name"]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my review, $index is not required at all for this issue. You can use filter for table ngRepeat.check this  [link]http://plnkr.co/edit/Hnb7hkjA16XDbzRT8VAt?p=preview

```
html code here: 
<table  border="1px" width="100%" ng-repeat="data in serviceData |limitTo:2 ">
 <tr>
     <td>{{data["service-name"]}}</td>
     <td>{{data.service}}</td>
</tr>
```